# Multi Level Drop Down Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, dropdown

I'm already try this [Multi-Level Drop Down](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h). When I have 2 or more dropdown submenu. When I click first dropdown and then I click another dropdown, the first dropdown still open. I want when I click second dropdown, the first dropdown will close or when I click head of dropdown all sub-dropdown will close.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: show us something, like script, html

Comment: run code snippet @Se0ng11

Comment: You should use: http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/

Comment: Try with some thing like this ... http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/oye7bq5q/

Comment: please script to answer

Comment: @Stfvns I'm fixing this problem it's very simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using CSS, jQuery `addClass('active')` & `toggleClass('active')` in CSS you have to make `display: none;` for all dropmenu

here you go

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

$(function () {
$('#drop1').on('click', function(){
  $('.dropmenu1').toggleClass('active');
    $('.dropmenu2').removeClass('active');
});

$('#drop2').on('click', function(){
  $('.dropmenu1').removeClass('active');
 $('.dropmenu2').toggleClass('active');
});

$('#drop3').on('click', function(){
  $('.dropmenu3').toggleClass('active');
});

$('#drop4').on('click', function(){
  $('.dropmenu4').toggleClass('active');
});
$('#button-t').on('click', function(){
  $('.dropmenu1').removeClass('active');
  $('.dropmenu2').removeClass('active');
  $('.dropmenu3').removeClass('active');
  $('.dropmenu4').removeClass('active');
});
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
ul.dropdown-menu ul.dropdown-menu{
  display:none !important;
}
ul.dropdown-menu ul.dropdown-menu.active{
  display:block !important;
}
ul.dropdown-menu ul
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="button-t">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#" id="drop1"> New dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropmenu1">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#" id="drop3">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropmenu3">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu" >
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#" id="drop2">New dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropmenu2">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#" id="drop4">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropmenu4">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your click handler to be a bit more generic. This will close any 'ul' at the same level accept for the one you are clicking on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
        let jSubMenu = $(this).next('ul');
        jSubMenu.toggle();
        if (jSubMenu.length > 0) {
            // Close any other 'ul' elements at the same level.
            let jOtherSubMenus = $(this).parent().parent().find('ul');
            jOtherSubMenus.each(function(index, el) {
              let jEl = $(el);
              if (el != jSubMenu[0] && jEl.css('display') == 'block') {
                jEl.toggle();
              }
            });
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```